# Insertar checkbox en tabla con VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

Llevo horas intentando insertar checkboxs en una tabla con Vue y me está resultando imposible.
Estoy usando primeVue para los componentes y por mucho que leo la documentación de la DataTable me está resultando imposible comprenderla.
Os paso una foto de lo que estoy intentando:
[image: Es en esa zona donde quiero los checkbox]

Cada vez que inserto el componente RadioButton de primeVue o me lo pone arriba fuera de la tabla o abajo fuera de la tabla.
Os paso el código por si os facilita la respuesta:

```
import Column from "primevue/column";
import DataTable from "primevue/datatable";
import { reactive } from "vue";
import Button from "primevue/button";
import RadioButton from "primevue/radiobutton";

const state = reactive<{
  tableItems: any[];
}>({
  tableItems: [],
});
setTimeout(() => {
  state.tableItems = [
    {
      policy: "Póliza",
      // eslint-disable-next-line sonarjs/no-duplicate-string
      name: "Nombre y Apellidos",
      age: "Edad",
      rol: "Rol",
      dni: "DNI",
    },
    {
      policy: "Póliza",
      name: "Nombre y Apellidos",
      age: "Edad",
      rol: "Rol",
      dni: "DNI",
    },
    {
      policy: "Póliza",
      name: "Nombre y Apellidos",
      age: "Edad",
      rol: "Rol",
      dni: "DNI",
    },
    {
      policy: "Póliza",
      name: "Nombre y Apellidos",
      age: "Edad",
      rol: "Rol",
      dni: "DNI",
    },
  ];
}, 2000);

function btnAlert() {
  alert("Abriendo!");
}
</script>

<template>
  <div id="app">
    <DataTable
      :value="state.tableItems"
      :paginator="true"
      :rows="10"
      :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 25, 50]"
      paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
      currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}"
    >
      <Column field="policy" header="Póliza"></Column>
      <Column field="name" header="Nombre y Apellidos"></Column>
      <Column field="age" header="Edad"></Column>
      <Column field="rol" header="Rol"></Column>
      <Column field="dni" header="DNI"></Column>
    </DataTable>
    <RadioButton />
    <Button type="submit" :label="'Abrir Caso'" @click="btnAlert" />
  </div>
</template>
```

He intentado poner el componente RadioButton dentro de DataTable, en Column, dentro de Column... y nada.

Comment: ¿Intentase usando [`templating`](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/datatable/templating)?

Comment: Sí, pero sigue sin cogerme el componente RadioButton, lo que si me coge es un input type radio, pero eso no me sirve

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu pregunta y agregar el código que has intentado y no te funciona?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda Marcos, acabo de conseguirlo, comparto el código por si alguien se frustra igual que yo xD

Answer (score 1):

Conseguido! Si alguien se atasca, comparto código.
Era usando template pero creando una columna nueva, gracias a Marcos por contestar :)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <DataTable
      :value="state.tableItems"
      :paginator="true"
      :rows="10"
      :rowsPerPageOptions="[10, 25, 50]"
      paginatorTemplate="CurrentPageReport FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink RowsPerPageDropdown"
      currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords}"
    >
      <Column field="cuadro">
        <template #body="{ data }">{{ data.cuadro }}<RadioButton /></template>
      </Column>
      <Column field="policy" header="Póliza"></Column>
      <Column field="name" header="Nombre y Apellidos"></Column>
      <Column field="age" header="Edad"></Column>
      <Column field="rol" header="Rol"></Column>
      <Column field="dni" header="DNI"></Column>
    </DataTable>
    <Button type="submit" :label="'Abrir Caso'" @click="btnAlert" />
  </div>
</template>
```